# How do I log a deny of connection to a specific port using firewalld?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, centos7

on my new CentOS7 box I tried to use the 'new' firewalld, but I am unable to log a dropped connection attempt.
Does someone know the trick?

I tried:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="10.1.2.0/24" port port="22" protocol="tcp" log prefix="SSH-ALLOW_" accept'
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="10.3.4.0/24" port port="22" protocol="tcp" log prefix="SSH-ALLOW_" accept'
[here comes a VERY VERY long list of similar entries]
```

And now the question: How do I specify a log entry for connection attempts from a not-allowed IP?
Something like the non-working:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="NOT-ONE-OF-THE-ABOVE" port port="22" protocol="tcp" log prefix="SSH-DENY_" drop'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a dated post, and my solution does not directly address the logging for a specific port, but I've been searching logging drops with firewalld.  There are many old posts and blogs that attempt to address this issue.

For the public, this update from Red Hat should be more available than only to subscribers:

Upgrade to firewalld-0.4.3.2-8.el7 from Errata RHSA-2016:2597

Specify which packets should be logged

firewall-cmd --set-log-denied=
value may be one of: all, unicast, broadcast, multicast, or off

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1191593

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  In both cases, invert address parameter.

For your example including the two shown subnets, change your original:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="NOT-ONE-OF-THE-ABOVE" port port="22" protocol="tcp" log prefix="SSH-DENY_" drop'
```

To these:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="10.1.2.0/24" invert=true port port="22" protocol="tcp" log prefix="SSH-DENY_" drop'
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="10.3.4.0/24" invert=true port port="22" protocol="tcp" log prefix="SSH-DENY_" drop'
```

This results in the following IP table rules being created by firewalld:

```
# iptables -S | grep _public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public_log ! -s 10.1.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix SSH-DENY_
-A IN_public_log ! -s 10.3.4.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix SSH-DENY_
```

The difference between the two rules in iptables speak is the '!' representing the logical operator "Not".  Your original rule to iptables:

```
-A IN_public_deny -s 10.1.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
-A IN_public_log -s 10.1.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix SSH-DENY_
```

HTH.